UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist
ITMS-90109: This bundle is invalid - The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions. Refer to QA1623 for additional information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html
I am getting this error when I submit my App to the Appstore.
I have this piece of code from the past 3 years in my info.plist file
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>


This error occurs because Apple has deprecated support for the armv7 architecture, and including it in your app's UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities can block submission to the App Store.
How to fix it: 
Remove UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities from your Info.plist if your app doesn't have specific hardware needs. Most modern iOS devices don't require this field anymore.
If you do need device capabilities, include only those your app truly requires. For example:
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <!-- Include only what you actually need, such as: -->
    <string>gps</string>
    <string>camera</string>
</array>

Key Points:

The armv7 architecture was used by 32-bit devices (e.g., iPhone 5 and earlier).
All modern iOS devices are 64-bit and use the arm64 architecture.
Apple dropped support for 32-bit apps with iOS 11 (released in 2017).
There's no need to explicitly list arm64 in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.

If your app doesn't require specific hardware, it's best to remove the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key from your Info.plist. This will ensure compatibility with all iOS devices that meet your minimum iOS version.
